# Removed console.logs in library still show on the client

Tags: javascript, angular

I had some console.logs in my library for test purposes and today I decided to remove them. After removing every log I built and published my library and installed it on my project. The console.logs are still showing allthough they're nowhere to be found in the code. but when I open the source tab in my browser inspector to see where the logs come from it still shows old code where the logs were still present. What can be the cause of this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you try to refresh your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes I have, didn't make a difference

Comment: Chrome? it likes to hang on to cache

Comment: Open the page in a new inkognito window. So you can be sure that there is nothing cached. Sometimes the CTRL+F5 cache reload does not work for me neither

Comment: Nope, Using Edge at the moment

Comment: Just tried the incognito mode but didn't do the trick either so I fear that it is no caching problem

Comment: How you have deployed the project?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue! Another library in this project which also uses this main library had an older version installed which still contained the logs

Answer (score 0):

Try to Disable the Cache with Dev Tools :

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings#general